# ElasticSearch - Create Query That Show Different Properties Between Two Indexes

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create an elastic query that will show non-common properties between two indexes. Say the first index is:

```
{
  "myFirstIndex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "CAT" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "DATE_OF_BIRTH" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "ID" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "NAME" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

, and the second was is:

```
{
  "mySecondIndex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "CAT" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        },
        "DATE_OF_BIRTH" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "ID" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have never done a query across indexes so I am not sure how to do this. I don't care much about whether the properties have nested characteristics. For my purposes, finding the appropriate common properties at a base level is sufficient.

Grateful for any assistance. Thank you

Comment: what exactly are you looking to return from this query?

Comment: @MarkWalkom I want returned any properties that are not common between the two indexes (originally I said the common ones, but the not-common is actually more useful). So, for the specific example here, I want "NAME" and "timestamp" returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(based off your clarifications) you can't do that natively in Elasticsearch

you'd need to run the queries from some code and then compare the two indices in said code

Comment: yes that's the conclusion I have come to. I am suprised there is no way to do this within elastic but I think you are correct.